# flask login: current user return anonymous after login

Tags: authentication, flask, flask-login

i am creating an app with flask login and sqlite3, but after successful login the user continues to be anonymous

this is my login page source code:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def data():
   if request.method == 'GET':
      if current_user.is_authenticated:
         return redirect("/control-panel")
      else:
         return render_template("login.html")         
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if current_user.is_authenticated:
         return redirect("/control-panel")
      else:
         print(request.form["username"])
         username = request.form["username"]
         #print(request.form["password"])
         password = request.form["password"]
         if search.login_user() == True:
            username_to = load_user(username)
            login_user(username_to, remember='y')
            print(user)
            return redirect("/control-panel")
        else:
            return render_template("incorrect-login-credentials.html")
     else:
        return redirect("/request-error")
```

practically, after logging in the user is redirected to the control panel only if he is authenticated, otherwise he is redirected to login.
each time, however, he is redirected to the login page.

this is my user class

```
class User(UserMixin):
   def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = str(id)
        self.authenticated = True
        self.active = True
   def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
   def is_active(self):
        return True
   def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
   def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance =)

Comment: What is `search.login_user()` ?

Comment: is to search the database for name and password and compare them with those provided by the user who wants to authenticate